# Possible to detect Javascript mouse event in a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, bookmarklet

I am specifically looking to get `event.screenX` and `event.screenY` - X and Y mouse position on the screen, at the moment a bookmarklet script is triggered. Is this possible?

The bookmarklet opens a new window, which I would like to position at the mouse location. Since the bookmarklet could be at any spot along the bookmarks bar, depending on where it is placed, I'd need to get this from the browser/screen.

I am sceptical that this can be done, but figured I'd ask before completely writing it off.

Comment: Do you mean position at the *time* the bookmarklet is triggered? Won't the mouse be hovering over the bookmark link at that time, under most circumstances?

Comment: Yep, sorry, to be clear: X/Y mouse position on the screen at the moment the bookmarklet is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I don't think this is possible, because you would need to receive mouse events outside of the current page's DOM.

(The Katamari Hack (http://kathack.com/) is an example of mouse-driven game distributed via bookmarklet. It works on whatever page you're looking at, after you press the bookmarklet, but only captures mouse events inside the DOM. Not that a negative example is proof.)

Comment: Thanks, however, I should have been more clear (clarification now added). I'm looking for the screen positions at the moment a bookmarklet is clicked in the bookmarks bar.